# Correct SPF record

Tags: spf, dmarc

I have been asked to apply DMARC protection to a domain. Part of this requires me to add an DNS record to the domain management console, however I have come across a stumbling block. The DMARC checker says there is a problem with the SPF record of my client's domain...

https://ibb.co/P4YGhJh

The problem is the Sabre part of the record which is using 13 lookups, but the maximum is 10. I have attempted to speak with Sabre technical support, who say that in order to help me, I will need a referral from my authorised Sabre distributor (which was probably a fob off because they didn't know) and as the domain holder is the customer, I don't have one.

Any suggestions to go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Look into spf flattening. This is a common issue and there are services, scripts, and procedures that can help navigate it.

Comment: Maybe give us the domain name so that we can check for ourselves. Your linked image is unreadable.

Comment: An include that in turn refers to `include:spf.provider.example` may indicate that your customer has included a record meant for a providers own mail domain, not the one provided for their clients to include when subscribed to specific services. Maybe the actually intended record would be a single lookup. Probably a good idea to confirm, even if it involves emailing your client with a request to forward to techsupport@provider.example.